# Spark Streaming Saving to Cassandra Table

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I have created a JavaPairInputDStream and trying to save the data consumed to Cassandra tables. But facing issues and not sure how to begin with the code:

This is the code that I have written for SparkStreaming:

```
package com.test.anna.KafkaSpark;

import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil.mapColumnTo;
import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraStreamingJavaUtil.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Function;

import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils;

import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.RowWriterFactory;

import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder;
import scala.Tuple2;
import java.util.Map;

public class SparkStreamingConsumer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .setAppName("kafka-sandbox")
                .setMaster("local[*]");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(20000));

        // TODO: processing pipeline
        Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap();
        kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
        kafkaParams.put("zookeeper.connect","localhost:2181");
        Set<String> topics = Collections.singleton("test6");
       System.out.println("Size of topic--->>>>"+topics.size());
        JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,
                String.class, String.class, StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams, topics);

        directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
            System.out.println("Message Received "+rdd.values().take(1));
            System.out.println("--- New RDD with " + rdd.partitions().size()
                + " partitions and " + rdd.count() + " records");
            rdd.foreach(record -> System.out.println(record._2));
            });

       directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd ->{            
            rdd.foreachPartition(item ->{
                while (item.hasNext()) {    


        ssc.start();
        ssc.awaitTermination();
    }

}
```

Kindly let me know how to save this data to Cassandra table, small piece code would help a lot :)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The docs cover that pretty well: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/8_streaming.md

Answer (score 0):

Use Datastax's spark-cassandra connector [spark-cassandra](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) and you can get jar from here [spark-cassandra connector jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10)

Here is the sample code

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;

SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
conf.setAppName(APP_NAME);
conf.setMaster(NODE);
conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", CASSANDRA_HOST);
conf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", CASSANDRA_USER);
conf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", CASSANDRA_PASS);

final JavaSparkContext jpc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
final CassandraConnector connector=CassandraConnector.apply(jpc.getConf());
final Session session=connector.openSession();
```

You can use this **Session**  object for saving data to a keyspace

Comment: Yeah this thing I have used. It is a simple insertion in Cassandra tables. I am looking for something where I can directly ingest the data coming from Spark streaming to Cassandra.